# How to store a huge base64 image in a String in Java? Do I use a different datatype?

Tags: java

I'm trying to store a base64 representation of an image in a String for later decoding and use. I want it in the program so it can't be deleted. It's going to be used for a watermark. I'm running into the issue of the string being too long - I get a pre-compile issue of "constant string too long" on this particular line (stackoverflow wouldn't let me post more than 30000 characters, so it's truncated at the end):

```
String image = "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......";
```

I could break the string into multiple strings perhaps, but I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require that.

I did run across this, saying that the max String size is 64K at compile time: [String error "constant string too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318659/string-error-constant-string-too-long/6318695)

Do I need to use a different data type? I am using NetBeans - in case there are built in tools to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason this can't go into the JAR?

Comment: So I googled JAR, it says it's Java Archive. How would I store it in here? It's just the output .jar file right?

Comment: Yes, the point is that you should store the watermark as a file inside that jar. You can still check in your code that the image is there and hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: But, I don't think there is a reason it can't go in the JAR

Comment: Oh okay, that's interesting. Is there a tool to do this?

Comment: have you compressed the image? To my understanding a watermark image should be a few KBs only. It need not be a high resolution image. You could possibly use a `String` array by splitting the actual Base64 value into multiple Strings.

Comment: Oh, I should compress it. I didn't think about that. That might solve the problem right there.

Comment: To store the image inside your jar just put it in a resource folder, to check for integrity you're looking for a checksum such as md5 or sha1sum ; Apache Commons Codec implement those (although I'm not sure it's the best choice of library for that task)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466728/238704) answer.

Comment: Also, you can use a denser encoding than base64. Base85 is fairly standard, or you can roll your own base94. I wouldn't bother really, just go with the resource-based answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Store it as a resource in your project, and read its contents using `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`:

```
  try (InputStream i = YourAwesomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/watermark.bin");
       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int n = 0; -1 != (n = i.read(buffer)); ) {
      bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
  }
```

As for your second answer, about JAR, it depends what you are using for building:

- Maven or Gradle handle that right out of the box; simply put your resources in `src/main/resources` while your classes will go to `src/main/java`.
- Eclipse allows you to extract a project as a JAR (see *File > Export* and search JAR); your resource simply needs to stay in the source folder (ex: `src/`). See this [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fexport_wizards%2Fexport_plugins.htm).
- [edit] did not see the Netbeans part: Netbeans probably have a Export as Jar.

Note that if you run your program from Eclipse, you won't need to export as a JAR (or use Maven): it is only if you need to export your program to someone else.

Comment: Resources should be in packages, not in the root of the .jar file.